# Display a message till all the packages are loaded

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have deployed one shiny application on my server using shiny server. The sample example is shown below:

**ui.R**

```
#library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

#filenames <- list.files(path = "data",pattern="\\.csv$")
#names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.csv$", "", filenames)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    headerPanel( 
      h3("Testing....",
         align="center", style="bold")
      )
    ),
  br(),
  br(),
  #useShinyjs(),  ## initialize shinyjs to reset input files.
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h5("Upload Data Files",style="bold"),
      fileInput("files", 
                "Choose CSV/txt processed files or raw files",
                multiple = "TRUE",
                accept=c('text/csv',
'text/comma-separated-values,
text/plain', '.csv','.cel','.TXT','.txt')),
#selectInput('dataset',"Choose platform annotation file", c("Please select a file" ='',filenames)),
fluidRow(
  column(5,
         radioButtons("radio", label = h5("Data uploaded"),
                      choices = list("Affymetrix" = 1, "Codelink" = 2,
                                     "Illumina" = 3),selected = NULL)
         )
  ),
fluidRow(
  column(10,
         h5("Differential Expression Call", style = "bold"),
         checkboxInput("checkbox",
                       label = "Differential Expression", value = FALSE))),
br(),
uiOutput('AnnotationFile')),
mainPanel(                      
  tabsetPanel(id = "MamgedTabs",
              tabPanel("Source-data", dataTableOutput("sourced")),
              tabPanel("Annotation-data",dataTableOutput("annotation"))
              )
  )
)
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
#library(gcrma)
#library(hgu133a.db)
#library(hgu133acdf)
#library(hgu133plus2.db)
#library(hgu133plus2cdf)
#library(hgu133a2frmavecs)
#library(hgu133b.db)
#library(hgu133bcdf)
#library(hgu219.db)
#library(hgu219cdf)
#library(hgu95a.db)
#library(hgu95acdf)
#library(org.Hs.eg.db)
#library(hgu133a2.db)
#library(hgu133a2cdf)
#library(hgu95av2.db)
#library(hgu95av2cdf)
#library(hgu133plus2cdf)
#library(affyPLM)
##library(makecdfenv)
#library(parallel)
#library(base)
#library(S4Vectors)
#library(IRanges)
#library(stats4)
#library(BiocInstaller)
#library(Biobase)
#library(BiocGenerics)
#library(BiocParallel)
#library(biomaRt)
#library(Biostrings)
#library(preprocessCore)
#library(affyio)
#library(zlibbioc)
#library(graphics)
#library(grDevices)
#library(methods)
#library(genefilter)
#library(stats)
#library(AnnotationDbi)
#library(utils)


## Defining the size of file to be accepted. Here it can accept any size.
options(shiny.maxRequestSize= -1) 

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  filenames <- list.files(path = "data", pattern="\\.txt$")
  names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.txt$", "", filenames)


  ## Dropdown box for chosing and loading annotation file
  output$AnnotationFile = renderUI({
    if(!input$checkbox | (input$checkbox == T && input$radio != 2)){
      wellPanel(
        h5("Upload Annotation File"),
        selectInput('dataset', "Choose platform annotation file",
                    c("Please select a file" = '', filenames), multiple = TRUE))
    }
  })
})
```

As you see in the `server.R`, I need many packages to be loaded, that takes some time. The below code

```
output$AnnotationFile = renderUI({
    if(!input$checkbox | (input$checkbox == T && input$radio != 2)){
      wellPanel(
        h5("Upload Annotation File"),
        selectInput('dataset', "Choose platform annotation file",
                    c("Please select a file" = '', filenames), multiple = TRUE))
    }
  })
```

is to show are hide something, takes some time to appear, because of the time it take to load the packages, but sometimes it does not display at all.

1) My application works fine locally, but shows this behavior, when deployed on the server. Any reason?

2) How can I display a message on the main panel that the application is getting ready till it load all the packages.

**Edit:** I can display the message inside shinyServer(), but that is for each session(will load all the packages again and again), however I want to show and load all the packages at the start of the application. In other words, it is to say that how to display progression message outside shinyServer()

Comment: `renderPrint` might be useful for you and inside that use `print` method to display your message.

Comment: You could use `busyIndicator` from the `shinysky` package. For more information follow this [link](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your application to wait till all the packages are loaded,you just  need to put all the packages in `ui.R`, the reason is simple, as the `ui.R` is getting executed before `server.R`. So you can put all the packages at the top of `ui.R`. When the application starts, it will load all the packages before showing you the interface that you have coded in `ui.R`, for example

```
#library(gcrma)
#library(hgu133a.db)
#library(hgu133acdf)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
# your code...
)
)
```

As you are using packages in `server.R`, it will show the application (`ui.R` part),but internally it will be loading all the packages, that will take some time, which user may not be knowing, eventually may lead to confusing about working of the application. To avoid that `ui.R` is a good option to have packages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a progress indicator or a modal dialog is what you want?

**UPDATE 2**

Here is an elaborated use of a progress bar for reading in a text file of 30 R packages, one per line:

```
# server.R
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = -1)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  withProgress(message = "Please wait", value = 0, expr = {
    for (i in 1:30) {
      source(textConnection(readLines("packages.txt", warn = FALSE)[i]))
      incProgress(amount = 1/30, detail = paste0("Loading package ", i, "/30"))
      Sys.sleep(time = 0.1)
    }
  })

  filenames <- list.files(path = "data", pattern = "\\.txt$")
  names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.txt$", "", filenames)

  output$AnnotationFile <- renderUI({
    if (!input$checkbox | (input$checkbox == T && input$radio != 2)) {
      wellPanel(
        h5("Upload Annotation File"),
        selectInput('dataset', "Choose platform annotation file", c("Please select a file" = '', filenames), multiple = TRUE)
      )
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks , where in `server.R`, if I include `library()` within the observe or progress indicator, the packages are not loaded

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but you know shiny packages are loaded before executing `shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {.....})`. Till everything is loaded, it will not display the message.

Comment: It works locally for me. Does not the code work for you?

Comment: Not working for me, can you provide an example of your code. Showing message is not a problem, but how to show it while loading all the packages.

Comment: Did you save your list of packages as a text file "packages.txt"?

Comment: I have provided a second update with the full server.R code.

Comment: How will it make sure that the package is actually load. Isn't reading the packages from the text file?. How do you actually measure the loading time?

Comment: When you runt the app, you can see in the console that the packages are being loaded. If you are using RStudio you can also see in the packages pane that the packages are being successfully loaded one by one.

Comment: Thanks , but putting the packages inside shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {.....}) loads them every time we refresh the application. If we use packages at the top, they are loaded only once.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I also doubt this solution would work on a server.